# How to store output(XML) of the PL/SQL in oracle table

Tags: xml, database, oracle, plsql, storage

I wrote a insert query which could get stored XML data in table as below:

```
INSERT INTO XmlTest VALUES (
  XMLType('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <RANK>1</RANK>
  <URBAN_AREA>Tokyo-Yokohama (Keihin)</URBAN_AREA>
  <COUNTRY>Japan</COUNTRY>
  <POPULATION>37126000</POPULATION>
 </ROW>
 </ROWSET>'
 ));
```

which is getting inserted successfully..XML which is present must be the output of the code written from PL/SQL which is :

```
DECLARE
   l_refcursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
   l_xmltype XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
   OPEN l_refcursor FOR select id,
       rank,
       urban_area,
       country,
       population      
from eba_dp_demo_table where country='China'  and population>3500000;
l_xmltype := XMLTYPE(l_refcursor);
dbms_output.put_line(l_xmltype.getClobVal);
```

basically iam trying to place the PL/SQL code in the place of XML code is there a way to do it..i coulnt achieve it it would be great if someone can help me out...

Comment: So What is the actual question?

Comment: I think your question is a little confusing. do you want convert the results of you cursor to an xml? why do you show how to insert xml into the datebele? where is the context?

Comment: I am trying to convert Report to XML and store it in table later fetch the XML data and convert it th PDF or other formats.  @hotfix.

Comment: @Tejash iam trying to place the PL/SQL code in place of XML .. But iam not able to do it.. Iam unsure whether that is even possible now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [XMLELEMENT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb13gen.htm#ADXDB4994) to generate XML tags you wanted from query script.

```
CREATE TABLE EBA_DP_DEMO_TABLE
AS
SELECT 1 ID_,1 RANK_, 'Tokyo-Yokohama (Keihin)' AS URBAN_AREA , 'Japan' COUNTRY ,'37126000' POPULATION FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 ID_,2 RANK_, 'Abidinpasa' AS URBAN_AREA , 'Turkey' COUNTRY ,'6666' POPULATION FROM DUAL;

DECLARE
   L_REFCURSOR   SYS_REFCURSOR;
   L_XMLTYPE     XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
   OPEN L_REFCURSOR FOR
      SELECT
            '<?xml version="1.0"?><ROWSET><ROW>'
             || ID
             || RANK
             || URBAN_AREA
             || COUNTRY
             || POPULATION
             || '</ROW></ROWSET>'
        FROM (SELECT XMLELEMENT ("ID", ID_) ID,
                     XMLELEMENT ("RANK", RANK_) RANK,
                     XMLELEMENT ("URBAN_AREA", URBAN_AREA) URBAN_AREA,
                     XMLELEMENT ("COUNTRY", COUNTRY) COUNTRY,
                     XMLELEMENT ("POPULATION", POPULATION) POPULATION
                FROM EBA_DP_DEMO_TABLE
               WHERE COUNTRY = 'Turkey');

   L_XMLTYPE := XMLTYPE (L_REFCURSOR);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (L_XMLTYPE.GETCLOBVAL);
END;
```